# Installation's object default ACL and security issue

Tags: android, parse-platform

I see on Data Browser that every new Installation's object has default ACL 'Public read and write' permissions.
What is a security risk?
And, if it is a security risk, how is possible solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the security part of the [development guide](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#security-security-edge-cases), you will see that `_Installation` table does not follow all the security rules of normal classes.

When dealing with `_User` and `_Installation` classes you end up with some security edge cases:

> Security Edge Cases
>
> There are some special classes in Parse that don't follow all of the same security rules as every other class. Not all classes follow Class-Level  Permissions (CLPs) or Access Control Lists (ACLs) exactly how they are  defined, and here those exceptions are documented. Here "normal behavior" refers to CLPs and ACLs working normally, while any other special behaviors  are described in the footnotes.

In order to perform `Delete` or `Find` operations on that table you require the master key. This means that a user cannot search the table for a specific record or delete one unless they have master key privileges.
You can only perform a `Get` operation which returns you a specific record as long as you know the `objectId` of that record. This protects the records in the `_Installation` table from being dumped by an unauthorized user.
So by default anyone can potentially create a record, read it or update it as long as they know its `objectId` but they will not be able to delete a record or query the whole table.

In a nutshell, there is some basic security applied to the `_Installation` table which protects the records against some unauthorized access, given that records in this table do not track any specific user. If you want to add more fields to the table or associate any record with a user, then you can use ACL permissions to customize such access as long as you consider the restrictions mentioned in the guide.

Comment: I tried to apply an exclusive ACL for automatic user on Installation object, but as consequence then I cant subscribe any channel or update any column.

Comment: You mean another user cannot update the record on the same device ?

Comment: I mean same user on same device, but I am new on Parse and I think that my code may be wrong.

Comment: You should be able to update a record as long as you have the proper ACL permissions and you are not affected by restrictions enforced by Parse on _Installation class.